# Cannot add property to Object, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to add a property to a nested Object in Javascript; however, when I set the property name and value the property fails to persist.

```
populated_post.comments[i].comment.end = true
console.log(typeof(populated_post));
console.log(typeof(populated_post.comments[i].comment));
console.log(populated_post.comments[i].comment);
```

The console:

```
object
object
{
  _id: 5f517998dce977a23c10b79a,
  post: 5f51718ac691e8a15f28d7de,
  sender: {
    _id: 5f5170e83e91eaa1580715a0,
    username: 'Patrick',
    password: 'foobar',
    bio: 'Hi, my name is Patrick',
    items: [],
    inbox: [],
    followers: [],
    following: [],
    contacts: [ [Object] ],
    __v: 0,
    profile_photo: '80becce309e4c6b02a0e9538559ed932'
  },
  date: 2020-09-03T23:17:44.028Z,
  message: '!',
  replies: [
    {
      comment_id: 5f5261aa5db43fa8d20dd668
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

As far as I can tell I am setting the property correctly. I do this multiple times throughout my app but it doesn't work here for some reason. Any thoughts?

Comment: can you also try `console.log(populated_post.comments[i].comment.end);`?

Comment: @Abhilash It's there. The console outputs a boolean. It's just not there when I send populated_post to the client.

Comment: there's a chance that the object is frozen. ```const X = Object.freeze({ firstProp: 1, secondProp: "Hi" }); X.third = true;``` this will silently block mutation of properties.

Comment: @Abhilash I know it's not frozen because I can mutate properties. I just can't add them.

Comment: thats right, my first question was to confirm that. do u have a working version somewhere like jsfiddle/codepen/codesandbox?

Comment: @Abhilash I think I found something. When I do console.log(Object.keys(populated_post.comments[i].comment)) I get [
  '$__',     'isNew',
  'errors',  '_doc',
  '$locals', '$op',
  '$init',   'end'
]

Comment: looks like the response has a customized toString(). None of these props are there in the JSON from `console.log`

Comment: @Abhilash any thoughts on how to add the property to the object's JSON?

Comment: can we talk over here? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221021/room-for-abhilash-and-julian-porter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Object is a Mongoose Object. Mongoose Objects have restrictions on their properties which prevent new properties from being added. The solution is to convert the Object to a plain JS Object via MongooseObject.toObject(), or the mongoose lean() function. Answered here:
[Can not add additional element to (mongoose) object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672217/can-not-add-additional-element-to-mongoose-object)